# In MySQL, how to return the week of the month?

Tags: mysql

The year is divided into 12 months. We can break down a month in four weeks.

In MySQL, how to return the week of the month? (Example: first week: 2 entries, second week: 5 entries, third week: 3 entries; fourth week: 8 entries)

Using Week and WeekOfYear not get the desired result because the functions return the week number YEAR, not month.

Comment: This isn't really Accurate.  Each of the twelve months has, on average, 4.3 weeks.  There are 52 weeks in a year (and sometimes, 53), not 48.

Comment: Calculating weeks is a bitch, if you say there are 4 weeks in a month you are also saying there are 48 weeks in a year, which is wrong. Look at MySQL's functions for interacting with weeks: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Comment: In most months, you'd have to either have a partial "week 5", of 2 or 3 days, or roll those extra days into the fourth week. If you're doing some type of analytics, those are going to play hell with your numbers either way. Best to do daily or monthly in that case, or to use week of year rather than week of month.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
FLOOR((DayOfMonth(dateCol)-1)/7)+1
```

I'd like to make it clear that this is probably not a good way to divide your data - (see the comments), but that this will get you as close as you can get.

Comment: this is not right, the doesnt give the num of the week of month which can be 1,2,3,4 or 5.

Comment: @julestruong How do you figure?

Comment: if your month starts on a Friday, and the date is the 4th, then you should be on week 2, but this only counts 7 day periods from the 1st; so, it will return 1.  It does not return the week component of the date.

Comment: This depends on the definition of "week of the month". If the "week" is defined e.g. from sunday to saturday, then the right approach is using function WEEK() (see below). However, if the "week" is defined to be from 1st to 7th day of the month (=first week), then from 8th to 14th (=second week) and so on, then this approach is correct. I personally would prefer this latter approach, because it is well defined, but for the "week of year" the WEEK() function.

Answer (score 18):

Use the MySQL built-in function week to find the week number for the year, then subtract the week number for the first day of the month.

```
SELECT WEEK('2012-02-20') - WEEK('2012-02-01')
```

there are plenty of options in the documentation to customize the call to fit exactly what you are looking for, but I hope my example gives you an idea of what is available to you.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Comment: I like this approach, but it is off by one. It should be `SELECT WEEK('2012-02-20') - WEEK('2012-02-01')  + 1`

Comment: For a given field from the table:
`WEEK(birth_date)-WEEK(DATE_FORMAT(birth_date,'%Y-%m-01'))`

Comment: I'd say WEEKOFYEAR may be better then WEEK

Answer (score 3):

Week of month (where the starting incomplete week is counted as a whole)

```
select ceiling((day(now()) - 
(6 - weekday(date_format(now(),'%Y-%m-01'))))/7) 
+ case when 6 - weekday(date_format(now(),'%Y-%m-01'))> 0 
then 1 else 0 end week_of_month;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT WEEK(my_date_field,5) - WEEK(DATE_SUB(my_date_field, 
INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(my_date_field) - 1 DAY),5) + 1
```

Or you can see [here](https://dreamdevourer.com/week-of-the-month-in-mysql/).

Answer (score -1):

SELECT
(WEEK('2020-09-27') - WEEK(DATE_FORMAT('2020-09-27','%Y-%m-01')))+1

Comment: take: 2010-04-01
According to week('2010-04-04') its the 14 week and week('2010-04-01') its the 13 week
The result will be that the 4th of April 2010 is in the second week

select (WEEK('2010-04-04') - WEEK(DATE_FORMAT('2010-04-04','%Y-%m-01')))+1;
Result:  2