# MySQL Select week number within current month

Tags: mysql

I have a table with events, some of which are recurring at spesific weeks within a month (Like, the 1st wednesday every month).

How would one select the below?

table

```
event  day         week
quiz   wednesday   1
```

pseudocode would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE week = weeknumberWithinCurrentMonth()
```

Since we are now in the third week of february, 0 rows would be fetched from the above pseudoquery. If we were in week 1 of february, it would have selected the example row.

Comment: is week is the column in your table with value 1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In MySQL, how to return the week of the month?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046729/in-mysql-how-to-return-the-week-of-the-month)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SELECT * FROM table WHERE week = FLOOR((DayOfMonth(NOW())-1)/7)+1

As close as you can get.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you are looking for:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

```
SELECT WEEK(CURDATE()) - WEEK(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() , '%Y-%m-01')) + 1
```