# Calculate a number of week in a month by Mysql

Tags: mysql

Calculate the exact number of week in a particular month of that year by Mysql query. 
for example i have to determine  the week number of this date 19-2-2015  by mysql?

I have tried this query but it fetch wrong result for the 2015 year:

```
SELECT WEEK(my_date_field,5) - 
WEEK(DATE_SUB(my_date_field, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(my_date_field)-1 DAY),5)+1
```

I only want to calculate the current week number of that month according to present calendar by mysql.

I have a database table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lcsi` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `batchID` datetime default NULL,
  `ticker` varchar(8) default NULL,
  `price` float(4,2) default NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

And and inserted data like

```
INSERT INTO `lcsi` (`id`, `batchID`, `ticker`, `price`, `date`) VALUES
(1, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'ACMTA', 11.65, '2003-12-16 16:27:37'),
(2, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'ACO', 16.61, '2003-12-16 16:27:37'),
(3, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'ADLTQ.OB', 0.31, '2003-12-16 16:27:37'),
(4, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'AHH', 20.75, '2003-12-16 16:27:38'),
(5, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'ALG', 15.18, '2003-12-16 16:27:38'),
(6, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'AMN', 34.89, '2003-12-16 16:27:38'),
(7, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'ARTW', 4.53, '2008-01-02 16:12:56'),
(8, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'ASVI', 30.59, '2003-12-16 16:27:38'),
(9, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'BZH', 99.66, '2003-12-16 16:27:39'),
(10, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'CALC', 10.85, '2003-12-16 16:27:39'),
(11, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'CAT', 80.26, '2003-12-16 16:27:39'),
(12, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'CAV', 2.98, '2003-12-16 16:27:39'),
(13, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'CENT', 26.00, '2003-12-16 16:27:40'),
(14, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'CLWY', 0.46, '2003-12-16 16:27:40'),
(15, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'CNH', 15.40, '2003-12-16 16:27:40'),
(16, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'DE', 63.82, '2003-12-16 16:27:40'),
(17, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'DEVC', 7.12, '2003-12-16 16:27:41'),
(18, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'DOW', 40.01, '2003-12-16 16:27:41'),
(19, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'ERSN.PK', 0.00, '2003-12-16 16:27:41'),
(20, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'F', 14.29, '2003-12-16 16:27:41'),
(21, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'FBST', 6.58, '2003-12-16 16:27:42'),
(22, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'FRK', 55.96, '2003-12-16 16:27:42'),
(23, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'FSHOX', 33.74, '2003-12-16 16:27:42'),
(24, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'GEHL', 12.52, '2003-12-16 16:27:42'),
(25, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'GM', 49.35, '2003-12-16 16:27:43'),
(26, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'GRIF', 14.35, '2003-12-16 16:27:43'),
(27, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'GVA', 23.50, '2003-12-16 16:27:43'),
(28, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'HAN', 34.28, '2003-12-16 16:27:43'),
(29, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'HBP', 2.90, '2008-01-02 16:12:44'),
(30, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'HD', 34.01, '2003-12-16 16:27:44'),
(31, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'HORT', 4.52, '2003-12-16 16:27:44'),
(32, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'JCTCF', 4.80, '2003-12-16 16:27:44'),
(33, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'KNUR.OB', 0.14, '2003-12-16 16:27:45'),
(34, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'LAF', 38.80, '2003-12-16 16:27:45'),
(35, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'LMT', 49.01, '2003-12-16 16:27:45'),
(36, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'LOW', 52.97, '2003-12-16 16:27:45'),
(37, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'LSCO', 13.46, '2003-12-16 16:27:46'),
(38, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'MHCO.PK', 1.60, '2003-12-16 16:27:46'),
(39, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'MHP', 68.05, '2003-12-16 16:27:46'),
(40, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'MKTAY', 9.55, '2003-12-16 16:27:46'),
(41, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'MLM', 45.42, '2003-12-16 16:27:47'),
(42, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'MRGO', 7.11, '2003-12-16 16:27:47'),
(43, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'MVCO', 1.60, '2003-12-16 16:27:47'),
(44, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'NEQS.PK', 0.05, '2003-12-16 16:27:47'),
(45, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'NWL', 21.83, '2003-12-16 16:27:48'),
(46, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'PHHM', 17.56, '2003-12-16 16:27:48'),
(47, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'POOL', 31.84, '2003-12-16 16:27:48'),
(48, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'RMIX', 6.25, '2003-12-16 16:27:48'),
(49, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'SEHI', 2.18, '2003-12-16 16:27:49'),
(50, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'SNA', 30.77, '2003-12-16 16:27:49'),
(51, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'TECUA', 45.64, '2003-12-16 16:27:49'),
(52, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'TII', 34.26, '2003-12-16 16:27:49'),
(53, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'TSCO', 39.24, '2003-12-16 16:27:49'),
(54, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'TTC', 45.84, '2003-12-16 16:27:50'),
(55, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'URI', 18.59, '2003-12-16 16:27:50'),
(56, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'USHG.OB', 0.55, '2003-12-16 16:27:50'),
(57, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'VOLVY', 29.99, '2003-12-16 16:27:50'),
(58, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'WIKS.OB', 0.35, '2003-12-16 16:27:51'),
(59, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'WMSI', 4.07, '2003-12-16 16:27:51'),
(60, '2003-12-16 11:26:04', 'WPEC.OB', 0.35, '2003-12-16 16:27:51'),
(61, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'ACMTA', 11.65, '2003-12-16 16:28:49'),
(62, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'ACO', 16.56, '2003-12-16 16:28:49'),
(63, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'ADLTQ.OB', 0.31, '2003-12-16 16:28:50'),
(64, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'AHH', 20.75, '2003-12-16 16:28:50'),
(65, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'ALG', 15.18, '2003-12-16 16:28:50'),
(66, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'AMN', 34.89, '2003-12-16 16:28:50'),
(67, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'ARTW', 4.53, '2003-12-16 16:28:51'),
(68, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'ASVI', 30.59, '2003-12-16 16:28:51'),
(69, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'BZH', 99.70, '2003-12-16 16:28:51'),
(70, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'CALC', 10.85, '2003-12-16 16:28:51'),
(71, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'CAT', 80.25, '2003-12-16 16:28:52'),
(72, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'CAV', 2.98, '2003-12-16 16:28:52'),
(73, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'CENT', 26.00, '2003-12-16 16:28:52'),
(74, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'CLWY', 0.46, '2003-12-16 16:28:52'),
(75, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'CNH', 15.35, '2003-12-16 16:28:52'),
(76, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'DE', 63.89, '2003-12-16 16:28:53'),
(77, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'DEVC', 7.12, '2003-12-16 16:28:53'),
(78, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'DOW', 40.01, '2003-12-16 16:28:53'),
(79, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'ERSN.PK', 0.00, '2003-12-16 16:28:53'),
(80, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'F', 14.28, '2003-12-16 16:28:54'),
(81, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'FBST', 6.58, '2003-12-16 16:28:54'),
(82, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'FRK', 56.00, '2003-12-16 16:28:54'),
(83, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'FSHOX', 33.74, '2003-12-16 16:28:55'),
(84, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'GEHL', 12.52, '2003-12-16 16:28:55'),
(85, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'GM', 49.41, '2003-12-16 16:28:55'),
(86, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'GRIF', 14.35, '2003-12-16 16:28:55'),
(87, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'GVA', 23.50, '2003-12-16 16:28:56'),
(88, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'HAN', 34.28, '2003-12-16 16:28:56'),
(89, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'HBP', 2.90, '2003-12-16 16:28:56'),
(90, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'HD', 34.02, '2003-12-16 16:28:57'),
(91, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'HORT', 4.52, '2003-12-16 16:28:57'),
(92, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'JCTCF', 4.80, '2003-12-16 16:28:57'),
(93, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'KNUR.OB', 0.14, '2003-12-16 16:28:57'),
(94, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'LAF', 38.80, '2003-12-16 16:28:58'),
(95, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'LMT', 49.01, '2003-12-16 16:28:58'),
(96, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'LOW', 53.01, '2003-12-16 16:28:58'),
(97, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'LSCO', 13.46, '2003-12-16 16:28:59'),
(98, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'MHCO.PK', 1.60, '2003-12-16 16:28:59'),
(99, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'MHP', 68.07, '2003-12-16 16:28:59'),
(100, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'MKTAY', 9.55, '2003-12-16 16:28:59'),
(101, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'MLM', 45.44, '2003-12-16 16:29:00'),
(102, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'MRGO', 7.11, '2003-12-16 16:29:00'),
(103, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'MVCO', 1.60, '2003-12-16 16:29:00'),
(104, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'NEQS.PK', 0.05, '2003-12-16 16:29:01'),
(105, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'NWL', 21.84, '2003-12-16 16:29:01'),
(106, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'PHHM', 17.56, '2003-12-16 16:29:01'),
(107, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'POOL', 31.83, '2003-12-16 16:29:01'),
(108, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'RMIX', 6.21, '2003-12-16 16:29:02'),
(109, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'SEHI', 2.18, '2003-12-16 16:29:02'),
(110, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'SNA', 30.77, '2003-12-16 16:29:02'),
(111, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'TECUA', 45.64, '2003-12-16 16:29:03'),
(112, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'TII', 34.34, '2003-12-16 16:29:03'),
(113, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'TSCO', 39.25, '2003-12-16 16:29:03'),
(114, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'TTC', 45.84, '2003-12-16 16:29:03'),
(115, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'URI', 18.59, '2003-12-16 16:29:04'),
(116, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'USHG.OB', 0.55, '2003-12-16 16:29:04'),
(117, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'VOLVY', 29.99, '2003-12-16 16:29:04'),
(118, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'WIKS.OB', 0.35, '2003-12-16 16:29:05'),
(119, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'WMSI', 4.07, '2003-12-16 16:29:05'),
(120, '2003-12-16 11:27:16', 'WPEC.OB', 0.35, '2003-12-16 16:29:05'),
(121, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'ACMTA', 11.65, '2003-12-16 16:49:09'),
(122, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'ACO', 16.62, '2003-12-16 16:49:09'),
(123, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'ADLTQ.OB', 0.31, '2003-12-16 16:49:09'),
(124, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'AHH', 20.85, '2003-12-16 16:49:10'),
(125, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'ALG', 15.20, '2003-12-16 16:49:10'),
(126, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'AMN', 34.95, '2003-12-16 16:49:10'),
(127, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'ARTW', 4.53, '2003-12-16 16:49:10'),
(128, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'ASVI', 30.65, '2003-12-16 16:49:11'),
(129, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'BZH', 99.99, '2003-12-16 16:49:11'),
(130, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'CALC', 10.85, '2003-12-16 16:49:11'),
(131, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'CAT', 80.35, '2003-12-16 16:49:11'),
(132, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'CAV', 3.00, '2003-12-16 16:49:12'),
(133, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'CENT', 26.20, '2003-12-16 16:49:12'),
(134, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'CLWY', 0.46, '2003-12-16 16:49:12'),
(135, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'CNH', 15.37, '2003-12-16 16:49:12'),
(136, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'DE', 63.92, '2003-12-16 16:49:13'),
(137, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'DEVC', 7.12, '2003-12-16 16:49:13'),
(138, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'DOW', 40.00, '2003-12-16 16:49:13'),
(139, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'ERSN.PK', 0.00, '2003-12-16 16:49:14'),
(140, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'F', 14.29, '2003-12-16 16:49:14'),
(141, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'FBST', 6.59, '2003-12-16 16:49:14'),
(142, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'FRK', 56.07, '2003-12-16 16:49:14'),
(143, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'FSHOX', 33.74, '2003-12-16 16:49:15'),
(144, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'GEHL', 12.47, '2003-12-16 16:49:15'),
(145, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'GM', 49.48, '2003-12-16 16:49:15'),
(146, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'GRIF', 14.35, '2003-12-16 16:49:16'),
(147, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'GVA', 23.54, '2003-12-16 16:49:16'),
(148, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'HAN', 34.25, '2003-12-16 16:49:17'),
(149, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'HBP', 2.85, '2003-12-16 16:49:17'),
(150, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'HD', 34.10, '2003-12-16 16:49:17'),
(151, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'HORT', 4.52, '2003-12-16 16:49:17'),
(152, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'JCTCF', 4.80, '2003-12-16 16:49:18'),
(153, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'KNUR.OB', 0.19, '2003-12-16 16:49:18'),
(154, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'LAF', 38.90, '2003-12-16 16:49:18'),
(155, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'LMT', 48.98, '2003-12-16 16:49:18'),
(156, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'LOW', 53.20, '2003-12-16 16:49:19'),
(157, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'LSCO', 13.46, '2003-12-16 16:49:19'),
(158, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'MHCO.PK', 1.60, '2003-12-16 16:49:19'),
(159, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'MHP', 68.11, '2003-12-16 16:49:20'),
(160, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'MKTAY', 9.55, '2003-12-16 16:49:20'),
(161, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'MLM', 45.58, '2003-12-16 16:49:20'),
(162, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'MRGO', 7.11, '2003-12-16 16:49:21'),
(163, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'MVCO', 1.60, '2003-12-16 16:49:21'),
(164, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'NEQS.PK', 0.05, '2003-12-16 16:49:21'),
(165, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'NWL', 21.79, '2003-12-16 16:49:21'),
(166, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'PHHM', 17.67, '2003-12-16 16:49:22'),
(167, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'POOL', 31.92, '2003-12-16 16:49:22'),
(168, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'RMIX', 6.25, '2003-12-16 16:49:22'),
(169, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'SEHI', 2.19, '2003-12-16 16:49:22'),
(170, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'SNA', 30.79, '2003-12-16 16:49:22'),
(171, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'TECUA', 45.73, '2003-12-16 16:49:23'),
(172, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'TII', 34.49, '2003-12-16 16:49:23'),
(173, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'TSCO', 39.26, '2003-12-16 16:49:23'),
(174, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'TTC', 46.15, '2003-12-16 16:49:23'),
(175, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'URI', 18.74, '2003-12-16 16:49:24'),
(176, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'USHG.OB', 0.55, '2003-12-16 16:49:24'),
(177, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'VOLVY', 29.99, '2003-12-16 16:49:24'),
(178, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'WIKS.OB', 0.35, '2003-12-16 16:49:24'),
(179, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'WMSI', 4.07, '2003-12-16 16:49:25'),
(180, '2003-12-16 11:47:36', 'WPEC.OB', 0.35, '2003-12-16 16:49:25'),
(181, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'ACMTA', 11.65, '2003-12-16 16:52:06'),
(182, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'ACO', 16.61, '2003-12-16 16:52:07'),
(183, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'ADLTQ.OB', 0.31, '2003-12-16 16:52:07'),
(184, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'AHH', 20.90, '2003-12-16 16:52:07'),
(185, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'ALG', 15.20, '2003-12-16 16:52:07'),
(186, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'AMN', 35.07, '2003-12-16 16:52:08'),
(187, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'ARTW', 4.53, '2003-12-16 16:52:08'),
(188, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'ASVI', 30.73, '2003-12-16 16:52:08'),
(189, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'BZH', 99.99, '2003-12-16 16:52:08'),
(190, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'CALC', 10.85, '2003-12-16 16:52:08'),
(191, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'CAT', 80.35, '2003-12-16 16:52:09'),
(192, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'CAV', 3.00, '2003-12-16 16:52:09'),
(193, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'CENT', 26.20, '2003-12-16 16:52:09'),
(194, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'CLWY', 0.46, '2003-12-16 16:52:09'),
(195, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'CNH', 15.32, '2003-12-16 16:52:10'),
(196, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'DE', 63.95, '2003-12-16 16:52:10'),
(197, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'DEVC', 7.12, '2003-12-16 16:52:10'),
(198, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'DOW', 40.01, '2003-12-16 16:52:10'),
(199, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'ERSN.PK', 0.00, '2003-12-16 16:52:11'),
(200, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'F', 14.30, '2003-12-16 16:52:11'),
(201, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'FBST', 6.59, '2003-12-16 16:52:11'),
(202, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'FRK', 56.06, '2003-12-16 16:52:11'),
(203, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'FSHOX', 33.74, '2003-12-16 16:52:12'),
(204, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'GEHL', 12.47, '2003-12-16 16:52:12'),
(205, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'GM', 49.47, '2003-12-16 16:52:12'),
(206, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'GRIF', 14.35, '2003-12-16 16:52:12'),
(207, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'GVA', 23.52, '2003-12-16 16:52:13'),
(208, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'HAN', 34.25, '2003-12-16 16:52:13'),
(209, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'HBP', 2.85, '2003-12-16 16:52:13'),
(210, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'HD', 34.20, '2003-12-16 16:52:13'),
(211, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'HORT', 4.52, '2003-12-16 16:52:14'),
(212, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'JCTCF', 4.80, '2003-12-16 16:52:14'),
(213, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'KNUR.OB', 0.20, '2003-12-16 16:52:14'),
(214, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'LAF', 38.90, '2003-12-16 16:52:14'),
(215, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'LMT', 48.96, '2003-12-16 16:52:15'),
(216, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'LOW', 53.13, '2003-12-16 16:52:15'),
(217, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'LSCO', 13.93, '2003-12-16 16:52:15'),
(218, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'MHCO.PK', 1.60, '2003-12-16 16:52:15'),
(219, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'MHP', 68.12, '2003-12-16 16:52:16'),
(220, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'MKTAY', 9.55, '2003-12-16 16:52:16'),
(221, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'MLM', 45.59, '2003-12-16 16:52:16'),
(222, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'MRGO', 7.11, '2003-12-16 16:52:16'),
(223, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'MVCO', 1.60, '2003-12-16 16:52:17'),
(224, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'NEQS.PK', 0.05, '2003-12-16 16:52:17'),
(225, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'NWL', 21.79, '2003-12-16 16:52:17'),
(226, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'PHHM', 17.67, '2003-12-16 16:52:17'),
(227, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'POOL', 31.92, '2003-12-16 16:52:18'),
(228, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'RMIX', 6.23, '2003-12-16 16:52:18'),
(229, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'SEHI', 2.15, '2003-12-16 16:52:18'),
(230, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'SNA', 30.79, '2003-12-16 16:52:18'),
(231, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'TECUA', 45.83, '2003-12-16 16:52:19'),
(232, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'TII', 34.50, '2003-12-16 16:52:19'),
(233, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'TSCO', 39.20, '2003-12-16 16:52:19'),
(234, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'TTC', 46.07, '2003-12-16 16:52:19'),
(235, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'URI', 18.75, '2003-12-16 16:52:20'),
(236, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'USHG.OB', 0.55, '2003-12-16 16:52:20'),
(237, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'VOLVY', 30.06, '2003-12-16 16:52:20'),
(238, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'WIKS.OB', 0.35, '2003-12-16 16:52:20'),
(239, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'WMSI', 4.07, '2003-12-16 16:52:21'),
(240, '2003-12-16 11:50:33', 'WPEC.OB', 0.35, '2003-12-16 16:52:21'),
(241, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'ACMTA', 11.65, '2003-12-16 16:57:03'),
(242, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'ACO', 16.59, '2003-12-16 16:57:03'),
(243, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'ADLTQ.OB', 0.31, '2003-12-16 16:57:03'),
(244, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'AHH', 20.94, '2003-12-16 16:57:03'),
(245, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'ALG', 15.20, '2003-12-16 16:57:03'),
(246, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'AMN', 35.07, '2003-12-16 16:57:03'),
(247, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'ARTW', 4.53, '2003-12-16 16:57:03'),
(248, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'ASVI', 30.72, '2003-12-16 16:57:04'),
(249, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'BZH', 99.99, '2003-12-16 16:57:04'),
(250, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'CALC', 10.85, '2003-12-16 16:57:04'),
(251, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'CAT', 80.31, '2003-12-16 16:57:04'),
(252, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'CAV', 3.00, '2003-12-16 16:57:04'),
(253, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'CENT', 26.20, '2003-12-16 16:57:04'),
(254, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'CLWY', 0.46, '2003-12-16 16:57:04'),
(255, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'CNH', 15.34, '2003-12-16 16:57:04'),
(256, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'DE', 63.86, '2003-12-16 16:57:05'),
(257, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'DEVC', 7.12, '2003-12-16 16:57:05'),
(258, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'DOW', 40.00, '2003-12-16 16:57:05'),
(259, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'ERSN.PK', 0.00, '2003-12-16 16:57:05'),
(260, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'F', 14.30, '2003-12-16 16:57:05'),
(261, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'FBST', 6.59, '2003-12-16 16:57:05'),
(262, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'FRK', 56.04, '2003-12-16 16:57:05'),
(263, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'FSHOX', 33.74, '2003-12-16 16:57:05'),
(264, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'GEHL', 12.47, '2003-12-16 16:57:05'),
(265, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'GM', 49.48, '2003-12-16 16:57:06'),
(266, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'GRIF', 14.35, '2003-12-16 16:57:06'),
(267, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'GVA', 23.50, '2003-12-16 16:57:06'),
(268, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'HAN', 34.25, '2003-12-16 16:57:06'),
(269, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'HBP', 2.85, '2003-12-16 16:57:06'),
(270, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'HD', 34.16, '2003-12-16 16:57:06'),
(271, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'HORT', 4.52, '2003-12-16 16:57:06'),
(272, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'JCTCF', 4.80, '2003-12-16 16:57:06'),
(273, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'KNUR.OB', 0.19, '2003-12-16 16:57:07'),
(274, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'LAF', 38.95, '2003-12-16 16:57:07'),
(275, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'LMT', 48.95, '2003-12-16 16:57:07'),
(276, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'LOW', 53.18, '2003-12-16 16:57:07'),
(277, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'LSCO', 13.93, '2003-12-16 16:57:07'),
(278, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'MHCO.PK', 1.60, '2003-12-16 16:57:07'),
(279, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'MHP', 68.10, '2003-12-16 16:57:07'),
(280, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'MKTAY', 9.55, '2003-12-16 16:57:07'),
(281, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'MLM', 45.56, '2003-12-16 16:57:08'),
(282, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'MRGO', 7.11, '2003-12-16 16:57:08'),
(283, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'MVCO', 1.60, '2003-12-16 16:57:08'),
(284, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'NEQS.PK', 0.05, '2003-12-16 16:57:08'),
(285, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'NWL', 21.70, '2003-12-16 16:57:08'),
(286, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'PHHM', 17.67, '2003-12-16 16:57:08'),
(287, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'POOL', 31.92, '2003-12-16 16:57:08'),
(288, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'RMIX', 6.25, '2003-12-16 16:57:08'),
(289, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'SEHI', 2.15, '2003-12-16 16:57:09'),
(290, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'SNA', 30.79, '2003-12-16 16:57:09'),
(291, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'TECUA', 45.95, '2003-12-16 16:57:09'),
(292, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'TII', 34.50, '2003-12-16 16:57:09'),
(293, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'TSCO', 39.27, '2003-12-16 16:57:09'),
(294, '2003-12-16 11:55:30', 'TTC', 46.13, '2003-12-16 16:57:09');
```

I am using this query :

```
SELECT week( batchID ) Week, year( batchID ) Year, month( batchID )
MONTH , SUM( price ) WeekAvg, ticker,batchID,
WEEK(batchID,5) - 
WEEK(DATE_SUB(batchID, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(batchID)-1 DAY),5)+1 as    WeekNumber
FROM lcsi_new_entry
WHERE batchID >= '2015-01-1 00:00:00'
AND batchID <= '2015-03-30 00:00:00'
GROUP BY week( batchID ) , year( batchID )  ,ticker
ORDER BY `batchID` DESC
```

Comment: you start the week on which day? Monday?

Comment: I think you're after the week number of a given date

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046729/in-mysql-how-to-return-the-week-of-the-month    here is your answer ;)

Comment: @Julo0sS ,i use this query from http://think-robot.com/2009/04/week-of-the-month-in-mysql/

Comment: FLOOR((DayOfMonth(dateCol)-1)/7)+1 @Julo0sS yes i tried this also but not getting according to calendar .can you please tell me what i sthe week number of the date 19-2-2015.

Comment: edit : ok, i see what you mean, gimme a moment

Comment: How do you define where the week number starts? The MySQL WEEK() function provides 7 "modes" for this. The WEEKDAY() function equates to mode 3 (Week 1 is the first week, with 4 or more days this year, Monday is First day of week) see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Comment: The answers are jumping around.  Please provide the 31 answers to the question as applied to every day in Jan, 2016.  This will weed out the Monday/Sunday discussion, the /7 solution, the week-week solution, etc, unless one of them really has the answer _you_ want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR("2015-02-01"); // = 5
```

This gives you the week number in 2015 for February 1 (5)

```
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR("2015-02-19"); // = 8
```

This gives you the week number for February 19th (8)
So, feb 19th is in the FOURTH week of february 2015...

1st february was Sunday. Last day of 5th year's week. 2nd of Feb was in the 6th week.... and now we're on the 4th. Just make this small calculation and add 1!

Comment: thanks julos but how i get that 19th date is in the fourth week of february in sql

Comment: look at my answer : 19th is in the 8th week of the year. Just check in which week 1st feb is, and with a small trick you get it... "searched day week" - "first day week" + 1 ...

Comment: yes i looked but i am new to sql ,how i get that 19th is fouth week of month by sql query what trick i have to use

Comment: SELECT ((SELECT WEEKOFYEAR("2015-02-19"))-(SELECT WEEKOFYEAR("2015-02-01")) +1) returns you "4"

Answer (score 0):

You have been using "mode 5" for the week calculation i.e.

1. a week starts on Monday and
2. week 1 starts at the first Monday of the year.

Changing either of those factors changes the calculated result.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b9b7/2)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`dt1` datetime, `dt2` datetime, `mode` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`dt1`, `dt2`, `mode`)
VALUES
    ('2015-02-01 00:00:00', '2015-02-19 00:00:00', 1),
    ('2015-02-01 00:00:00', '2015-02-19 00:00:00', 2),
    ('2015-02-01 00:00:00', '2015-02-19 00:00:00', 3),
    ('2015-02-01 00:00:00', '2015-02-19 00:00:00', 4),
    ('2015-02-01 00:00:00', '2015-02-19 00:00:00', 5),
    ('2015-02-01 00:00:00', '2015-02-19 00:00:00', 6),
    ('2015-02-01 00:00:00', '2015-02-19 00:00:00', 7)
;

CREATE TABLE WeekModes
    (`Mode` int, `First_day` varchar(6), `Range` varchar(4), `Week_1_is` varchar(29))
;

INSERT INTO WeekModes
    (`Mode`, `First_day`, `Range`, `Week_1_is`)
VALUES
    (0, 'Sunday', '0-53', 'with a Sunday in this year'),
    (1, 'Monday', '0-53', 'with 4 or more days this year'),
    (2, 'Sunday', '1-53', 'with a Sunday in this year'),
    (3, 'Monday', '1-53', 'with 4 or more days this year'),
    (4, 'Sunday', '0-53', 'with 4 or more days this year'),
    (5, 'Monday', '0-53', 'with a Monday in this year'),
    (6, 'Sunday', '1-53', 'with 4 or more days this year'),
    (7, 'Monday', '1-53', 'with a Monday in this year')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
      t1.dt1, t1.dt2, t1.mode, week(t1.dt1,t1.mode), week(t1.dt2,t1.mode), w.First_day, w.Week_1_is
FROM table1 t1
inner join weekmodes w on t1.mode = w.mode
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b9b7/2/0)**:

```
|                             DT1 |                             DT2 | MODE | WEEK(T1.DT1,T1.MODE) | WEEK(T1.DT2,T1.MODE) | FIRST_DAY |                     WEEK_1_IS |
|---------------------------------|---------------------------------|------|----------------------|----------------------|-----------|-------------------------------|
| February, 01 2015 00:00:00+0000 | February, 19 2015 00:00:00+0000 |    1 |                    5 |                    8 |    Monday | with 4 or more days this year |
| February, 01 2015 00:00:00+0000 | February, 19 2015 00:00:00+0000 |    2 |                    5 |                    7 |    Sunday |    with a Sunday in this year |
| February, 01 2015 00:00:00+0000 | February, 19 2015 00:00:00+0000 |    3 |                    5 |                    8 |    Monday | with 4 or more days this year |
| February, 01 2015 00:00:00+0000 | February, 19 2015 00:00:00+0000 |    4 |                    5 |                    7 |    Sunday | with 4 or more days this year |
| February, 01 2015 00:00:00+0000 | February, 19 2015 00:00:00+0000 |    5 |                    4 |                    7 |    Monday |    with a Monday in this year |
| February, 01 2015 00:00:00+0000 | February, 19 2015 00:00:00+0000 |    6 |                    5 |                    7 |    Sunday | with 4 or more days this year |
| February, 01 2015 00:00:00+0000 | February, 19 2015 00:00:00+0000 |    7 |                    4 |                    7 |    Monday |    with a Monday in this year |
```