# Mysql Group by date week selection duplicates a week

Tags: mysql

I need to select billings and create a specific weekly calendar.

here is my query

```
SELECT billing_date FROM tabde GROUP BY week(billing_date);
```

and what i get is this result for February 2016

```
$result = array(
  array('billing_date' => '2016-01-01'),
  array('billing_date' => '2016-01-03'),
  array('billing_date' => '2016-01-10'),
  array('billing_date' => '2016-01-17'),
  array('billing_date' => '2016-01-24')
  );
```

this is a duplicate since both of these days comes under the same week

```
array('billing_date' => '2016-01-01'),
array('billing_date' => '2016-01-03'),
```

Comment: you understand that your query is senseless ? you can't group on a field that have different value without a grouping function...

Comment: I have a records table with a billing_date date column that has date "2016-01-01" like this and i want to group these based on another parent query. how do i group such dates as month weeks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confused about how `YEARWEEK` works. From the [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek):

> Returns year and week for a date. The year in the result may be
>   different from the year in the date argument for the first and the
>   last week of the year.

By a (not so strange) convention, January 1st, 2016 is in the 52nd week of 2015, since it was a Friday; January 3rd was a Sunday, and is instead in the 1st week of 2016. You can slightly alter this mechanism with the optional second parameter `mode`, which allows you to specify the first day of the week. See the [docs for the `WEEK` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) for details about that.

**EDIT**

Since you seem to be looking for a way to group your data by the week **in the month**, you could try something like this:

```
GROUP BY FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(billing_date) - 1) / 7) + 1
```

Basically, you take the day number and divide by 7 (with the necessary calculation adjustments). This is from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12046763/1882497), and comes with a similar warning: it's a bit of a weird way to divide your data. In particular, this assumes that you always count the weeks starting from the first day of the month, and of course different months will have a different amount of weeks. It should do what you want, though.

Comment: the group by week(billing_date, 0) also returns the same values how do i avoid the duplicates?

Comment: WEEK does exactly the same. You can't avoid situations like these if you use the week number, as the first days of January will almost always be in the last week of the year before. So the point is, what is your grouping logic? How would you explain it in words?

Comment: There are entries for everyday of a month i want to group a month by its weeks and just get any date of the week that doesn't matter i have another query that takes care of the rest i just need this query to show me 4 weeks result for every month with a date for that week.

Comment: Thank you @Aioros GROUP BY FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(billing_date) - 1) / 7) + 1 did the trick

Comment: Hi this won't be solution i think. If billing  date starts from 2017-01-16 and end from 2017-01-24 in this case what will happend ?

Answer (score 2):

> this is a duplicate since both of these days comes under the same week

Well, it depends on what day you consider the start of your week!

If you take a look at mysql documentation on [yearweek()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) function,, then you will see that it has a 2nd optional parameter, called mode:

> The mode argument works exactly like the mode argument to WEEK(). For
>   the single-argument syntax, a mode value of 0 is used.

If you look up the meaning of `mode` parameter under [week() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week), then you will see that 0 means Sunday is considered the 1st day of a week. `2016-01-03` was a Sunday.

Comment: group by week(billing_date, 0) also returns the same values

Comment: Of course it does, since week(billing_date, 0) = week(billing_date) ! You should use week(billing_date, 1) to have Monday as the 1st day of the week, not Sunday.

Comment: @Shadow week(billing_date, 1) this is the correct one